# Angular Date pipe, and a simple timer with Momentjs

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I've got the following code, which is supposed to find the difference in milliseconds from one date, to another. It's meant to get the elapsed time since a view has been opened:

```
  this.timer.start = new Date();
    this.timer.intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
      this.timer.elapsedTime = moment(new Date()).diff(this.timer.start)
    }, 1000);
```

Then, in the template, it's shown as this:

```
{{ timer?.elapsedTime | date: 'hh:mm:ss' }}
```

It should display something like:

```
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
...
```

And the minutes and seconds part, work well. But the "hours" part, is starting always with 1, therefore giving me this output:

```
01:00:01
01:00:02
01:00:03
...
```

Can someone explain me what I've got wrong, and why it's working like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment.diff` return a duration and not a Date object.

You can use `.duration` and format with the desired output.

```js
this.timer = {};
let start = moment(new Date());
let intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
  let elapsedTime = moment(new Date()).diff(start)
  let time = moment.duration(elapsedTime)

  let hrs = ('0' + time.hours()).slice(-2);
  let mins = ('0' + time.minutes()).slice(-2);
  let secs = ('0' + time.seconds()).slice(-2);

  this.timer.elapsedTime = `${hrs}:${mins}:${secs}`
  console.log(this.timer.elapsedTime)
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nope, still having the same behavior :(

Comment: @Zerok True, I updated my answer with the correct solution.

Comment: This works better! Yeah, I realized that a hand-made solution like this was needed. Thank you!